# Panama Papers Scandal: Is a salary "withdrawn?"

Tags: constitutional-law

The Prime Minister of Pakistan is facing an inquiry under a constitutional petition praying that the PM should be disqualified under sections 62 and 63 of the Constitution where a Member of the National Assembly must be, among other things, honest. Here is the full text of the April 20th judgement (which ruled 3-2 in favour of further investigation opposed to disqualification). http://www.supremecourt.gov.pk/web/user_files/File/Const.P._29_2016.pdf

Further investigation, among many things, discovered that the Prime Minister had an employment visa in the UAE. On the visa application made by a UAE company he is a "marketing manager" and the chairman of a company (owned by his son) with a salary of 10,000AED.

The PM was required to disclose his income sources as "assets" on his election nomination papers. In a written reply to the Supreme Court, just after the Court has reserved its judgement, he says that he did not withdraw any salary and therefore was not required to disclose it.

None of the five judges have said many good things about the PM in their original judgement. However, the only power to disqualify the PM the Supreme Court has in this case is if they believe the PM was dishonest. The Court has already made it known that a criminal trial for corruption, forgery, fraud and perjury against the PM and family will follow but everyone (including the judges themselves) have reservations about the conduct of institutions that will eventually prosecute them.

The judges have already concluded that a false or missing declaration on the ECP form suggests dishonesty. Was the PM dishonest by not disclosing a salary that he was not withdrawing?

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, irrespective of if he receives payment or not, he is *entitled* to the salary. As such, it is an asset belonging to the PM and should have been disclosed.

Whether this is *dishonest* or not is for the court to decide. It could have been an honest mistake.

Comment: It's not an honest mistake. The Court will not buy that. Even the PM's counsel has not said anything about this being an honest mistake where as according to him many other "honest mistakes" have been made by the respondent and others, including foreign governments.

Comment: @greatone I admire your prescience but if we knew the result of court decisions before they were made there would be no need to actually have courts

Comment: The PM has been disqualified for not being "honest" by a unanimous 5-0 verdict.

Answer (score 0):

The verdict of the Supreme Court reaffirms what @Dale M has said.

> The next question emerging for the consideration of this Court is
>   whether respondent No. 1 as a Chairman of the Board of Capital FZE is entitled
>   to salaries and whether the salaries if not withdrawn being receivable as such
>   constitute assets which require disclosure in terms of Section 12(2) of the
>   Representation of the People Act, 1976 and whether his failure to disclose
>   them would entail his disqualification? The word asset has not been defined in
>   the Representation of the People Act, 1976, (“ROPA”), therefore, its ordinary
>   meaning has to be considered for the purposes of this case. The word asset as
>   defined in Black’s Law Dictionary means and contemplates “an asset can be (i)
>   something physical such as cash, machinery, inventory, land and building (ii) an
>   enforceable claim against others such as accounts receivable (iii) rights such as
>   copyright, patent trademark etc (iv) an assumption such as goodwill”. The
>   definition of the word receivable as used in the above mentioned definition as
>   given in the Black’s Law Dictionary is also relevant which means and
>   contemplates “any collectible whether or not it is currently due. That which is
>   due and owing a person or company. In book keeping, the name of an account
>   which reflects a debt due. Accounts receivable a claim against a debtor usually 
>   arising from sales or services rendered”. The word ‘receivable’ also has similar
>   ring and connotation according to Business Dictionary which reads as under:-
>   “Accounting term for amount due from a customer, employee, supplier (as a
>   rebate or refund) or any other party. Receivables are classified as accounts
>   receivable, notes receivable etc and represent an asset of the firm”.
>   The definitions reproduced above leave no doubt that a salary not withdrawn
>   would nevertheless be receivable and as such would constitute an asset for all
>   legal and practical purposes. When it is an asset for all legal and practical
>   purposes, it was required to be disclosed by respondent No. 1 in his
>   nomination papers in terms of Section 12(2) of the ROPA. When we
>   confronted, the learned Sr. ASC for respondent No. 1, whether the said
>   respondent has ever acquired work permit (Iqama) in Dubai, remained
>   Chairman of the Board of Capital FZE and was entitled to salary as such, his
>   reply was in the affirmative with the only addition that respondent No. 1 never
>   withdrew any salary. This admission was reiterated in more categorical terms in
>   the written arguments filed by the learned Sr. ASC for respondent No. 1 in the
>   words as under:-
>   “So far as the designation of Respondent No. 1 as Chairman of the Board is
>   concerned, this was only a ceremonial office acquired in 2007 when the
>   respondent No. 1 was in exile, and had nothing to do with the running of the
>   Company or supervising its affairs. Similarly, the respondent No. 1 did not
>   withdraw the salary of AED 10,000. Thus, the salary shown in the Employment
>   Contract in effect never constituted an “asset” for the respondent No. 1.”
>
> It has not been denied that respondent No. 1 being Chairman of the
>   Board of Capital FZE was entitled to salary, therefore, the statement that he did
>   not withdraw the salary would not prevent the un-withdrawn salary from being
>   receivable, hence an asset. When the un-withdrawn salary as being receivable
>   is an asset it was required to be disclosed by respondent No. 1 in his
>   nomination papers for the Elections of 2013 in terms of Section 12(2)(f) of the
>   ROPA. Where respondent No. 1 did not disclose his aforesaid assets, it would
>   amount to furnishing a false declaration on solemn affirmation in violation of
>   the law mentioned above, therefore, he is not honest in terms of Section
>   99(1)(f) of the ROPA and Article 62(1)(f) of the Constitution of the Islamic
>   Republic of Pakistan.

http://www.supremecourt.gov.pk/web/user_files/File/Const.P._29_2016_28072016.pdf